# Why perl parses regex

Tags: perl

Perl misses my DWIM (ternary `?:`) and forces regex.

```
perl -e "print $bool ?'T' :'F'"
Use of ?PATTERN? without explicit operator is deprecated at -e line 1.
Search pattern not terminated or ternary operator parsed as search pattern at -e
 line 1.
```

Why is that so?
Following two examples have correctly parsed ternary operator,

```
perl -e "print $bool ? 'T' :'F'"
perl -e "print [] ?'T' :'F'"
```

This is on windows, but almost same thing on *nix

```
perl -e 'print $bool ?"T" :"F"'
```

so it doesn't look like shell related.

Comment: Looks like one of those parsing confusions in Perl that arise out of backwards compatibility. Typing "use of pattern without explicit operator" on Google gives many results, all similarly unrelated to pattern matching. And the fact that a single space makes the difference between error and no error is just yuk!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `?...?` is an operator, as seen [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#?PATTERN?msixpodualgc), and the problem here is one of ambiguity. The compiler does not know if it is seeing a pattern or a ternary operator (as the subsequent warning says), so it guesses, and guesses wrong.

I think it has something to do with `print()` setting it up for a fall, in that `print()` has the syntax:

```
print FILEHANDLE LIST
```

So, it pre-determines `$bool` as a file handle, and `?'....` as a statement. Then it notices that `$bool` is not a file handle, but the ternary is already cast in its faulty role. You will notice that the following works as intended:

```
perl -e"print STDOUT $bool ?'t' :'f'"
```

Comment: It is interesting to see that parens are of no help at all `perl -e "print ($bool ?'T' :'F')"` still gives error

Comment: `print(FILEHANDLE LIST)` and `print(LIST)` are perfectly valid, so the ambiguity remains.

Comment: @mpapec There really is no difference, since this is not a matter of precedence or function parameters. It has to do with the [indirect object notation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax).

Answer (score 6):

Perl syntax has ambiguities.

```
print $bool ?...
```

can be parsed as

```
print FILEHANDLE LIST

  +----------------- print
  |     +----------- FILEHANDLE
  |     |    +------ LIST (A regex match ?...?)
  |     |    |       
_____ _____ ____
print $bool ?...
```

or as

```
print LIST

  +----------------- print
  |       +--------- LIST (A conditional operator ...?...:...)
  |       |         
_____ __________
print $bool ?...
```

Without looking too far ahead, `perl` incorrectly guesses that you meant the first one, but lets you know that it guessed.

```
Search pattern not terminated or ternary operator parsed as search pattern
```

Workarounds:

- Adding a space after the `?` (`print $bool ? 'T' :'F';`) makes it guess correctly (since it no longer looks as much like `?...?`).
- Adding a `+` before the file handle (`print +$bool ?'T' :'F';`) makes it guess correctly (since it's no longer a valid file handle expression).
- Remove the space before the `?` (`print $bool?'T' :'F';`) makes it guess correctly (since it's no longer a valid file handle expression).
- Adding a file handle (`print STDOUT $bool ?'T' :'F';`) makes it guess correctly (since `$bool` must now be the start of the argument list).

Comment: (Yeah, this is mostly a rehash, but there was no accepted answer at the time, and I tried to make the explanation crystal clear.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you on Windows or on *nix?

On linux I get no warnings when I switch " and ' ( `perl -e 'print $bool ? "T" :"F"'`). The way you wrote it the `$bool` is interpolated by the shell, to an empty string, and your code becomes `perl -e "print  ?'T' :'F'"` which correctly triggers the warning.

Comment: almost same story with `perl -e 'print $bool ?"T" :"F"'` under linux so it's NOT shell related

Comment: weird. Especially as Deparse thinks the 2 versions (with and without the space between the question mark and the quote) are the same, try `perl -MO=Concise -e'print $bool ? "F" : "T"'` vs `perl -MO=Concise -e'print $bool ?"F" : "T"'`

Comment: unfortunately `Concise` doesn't show anything when there is no space after `?` mark

Comment: it does for me, in perl 5.16.3, with the "outer" single quotes.

Comment: wait, no it doesn't, I had no space between `$bool` and `?`